# Google Chrome new Secure Preferences, how mod sec preferences now?

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, installation

In new Сhrome version 37.0.2062.120 m appeared new Secure Preferences file, how make modification preferences now?

Secure Preferences file:

```
{
"extensions": {
"settings": {
}
},
"protection": {
"macs": {
"browser": {
"show_home_button": "6F07A285FE2C96A4DFF2CA4CA5783179E9C811CBC11DCDDBFB134EDCF6A3744C"
},
"extensions": {
"aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbcccccccccc": "11D619FC1E8DD99DF100E17B1D95F64D3C46BF6A5538D6031C80608720D9BDAD",
}
}
}
}
```

What is this protect mac code "11D619FC1E8DD99DF100E17B1D95F64D3C46BF6A5538D6031C80608720D9BDAD"? Is it hash code? How correct generate this code?